# Function which implement PAM algorithm in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is in matlab function which is implementing PAM algorithm (Partitioning around medoids) ? I am really confused, because I can not find anything about it even in mathworks...

Answer (score 0):

There is a File Exchange found at:

[Link for PAM algorithm File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26539-matex-matlab-extremes/content/KMedoidshort.m)

Comment: Ok, but I am looking for something like for k-means:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html

Am I right, there is not?

Comment: Do you have the statistics toolbox with Matlab? You can check this by entering ver in the command line. If so kmeans is built in function.

Comment: Yes I have statistics toolbox

Comment: Then you have kmeans ready to go and do not need any file exchange for it. So you are all good.

Comment: You can try it out with a simple example. Try a = rand(5); k = kmeans(a,2). This will give you a vector output of which cluster each row is in. There will be 2 clusters.